# how to create a folder according to calendar widgets pyqt5?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, qt-designer

[image]

I'm made this UI using pyqt5 designer .

Is it possible that when a day(example:22-6-2021) is selected in calendar **all files in folder** '22-6-2021' shown in a list as in the image and if no files are found **a folder is created with some date format**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The process is:

- Get the QDate selected in the QCalendarWidget and convert it to a string using a certain format.
- Using the previous string, do the search in the main directory, and if it does not exist then create the directory.
- Use the directory that matches the format to set as rootIndex of the QFileSystemModel of the QListView.

```py
import os
import sys
from pathlib import Path


from PyQt5.QtCore import QDir
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QCalendarWidget,
    QFileSystemModel,
    QListView,
    QVBoxLayout,
    QWidget,
)

CURRENT_DIRECTORY = Path(__file__).resolve().parent


class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, root_directory, date_format="dd-M-yyyy", parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._root_directory = root_directory
        self._date_format = date_format

        self.calendar_widget = QCalendarWidget()
        self.list_view = QListView()

        lay = QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.calendar_widget)
        lay.addWidget(self.list_view)

        self.model = QFileSystemModel()
        self.model.setRootPath(os.fspath(self.root_directory))

        self.calendar_widget.selectionChanged.connect(self.handle_selection_changed)

    @property
    def root_directory(self):
        return self._root_directory

    @property
    def date_format(self):
        return self._date_format

    def handle_selection_changed(self):
        if self.list_view.model() is None:
            self.list_view.setModel(self.model)
        dt = self.calendar_widget.selectedDate()
        dt_str = dt.toString(self.date_format)
        folder = os.fspath(self.root_directory / dt_str)
        if not QDir(folder).exists():
            QDir().mkdir(folder)
        self.list_view.setRootIndex(self.model.index(folder))


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    widget = Widget(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)
    widget.show()
    widget.resize(640, 480)
    widget.show()
    app.exec_()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you so much for you answer, but is there a way to select the date the calendar started on? For example if you run your code and today is 30 so automatically selected . Nothing is shown in the list and if you tried to select 30 nothing will be shown/created you have to select another date then select 30 again for it to work

Comment: @Kok129 Please understand my code and don't just copy the code, the solution is trivial: add `self.handle_selection_changed()` after `self.calendar_widget.selectionChanged.connect(self.handle_selection_changed)`.

Comment: I did understand your code yet I'm still new with pyqt5 thanks for your help!! God bless you

Answer (score -1):

maybe i can give you the main idea..
you can make an event listener for the calendar which will create folders

```
....
self.calendar.selectionChanged.connect(self.calendarListener)

def checkFolders(self, date):
    directory = os.getcwd()
    ls = os.listdir(directory)

    for f in ls:
        if f != date:
            new_dir = os.path.join(directory, date)
            os.mkdir(new_dir)

def calendarListener(self):
    qdate = self.calendar.selectedDate()
    y = qdate.year()
    m = qdate.month()
    d = qdate.day()
    date = str(d) + "-" + str(m) + "-" + str(y)
    print(date)
    self.checkFolders(date)
```